# Accessing public google calendars without auth

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-java-client

There are lot of public calendars like

> https://www.google.com/calendar/htmlembed?src=en-gb.christian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com&ctz=Asia/Calcutta

which does not require user to login.
I've checked Google calendar apis. It requires user to login and Auth to access even public calendars.
Am I missing something? Is it possible to access public calendar without auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access public calender without oauth token. As [Google](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth) says:

> Every request your application sends to the Google Calendar API must include an authorization token. The token also identifies your application to Google.

You need a service account for this scenario, service account is an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end user. For example, if you use the Google Prediction API to act on behalf of your application without accessing any user data, your application uses its service-account credentials to prove its own identity, and no end user is involved.

Here is the [service account guide](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Comment: Do I have to login again and again using auth token? as "Access tokens issued by the Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server expire one hour after they are issued."

Comment: Right. No refresh token for service account.